# Shell script + simulation keyboard key presed

Tags: shell

I have a simple question.

Is that possible to simulate an keyboard action ie: ctrl-a d  for detach a screen in a script,

I need this to check in the screen the folowing keyword "SEGFAULT" an then restart the processus.

If you have any suggestion...

Best regards

Paca

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) was written for. :)